# Simple Injector scope with DbContext

Tags: dependency-injection, simple-injector

Im using simple injector.

I have an mvc project that also has ApiControllers.

Here is my setup:

```
 public static class SimpleInjectorWebApiInitializer
{
    /// <summary>Initialize the container and register it as Web API Dependency Resolver.</summary>
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        var container = new Container();
        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();

        InitializeContainer(container);

        container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        // This is an extension method from the integration package.
        container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        container.Verify();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
       // GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    }

    private static void InitializeContainer(Container container)
    {
        container.Register<DbContext, CoreContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
    }
}
```

However this gives me the error:

> The configuration is invalid. The following diagnostic warnings were
>   reported:
>   -[Lifestyle Mismatch] UnitOfWork (Async Scoped) depends on CoreContext (Transient).

Comment: Why did you comment out the dependency resolver for webapi?

Comment: Can you please post the full exception message? The complete message is longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UnitOfWork` class depends on `CoreContext`, but you didn't register `CoreContext` as a service, but only as an implementation. Simple Injector will only look for registration of services, but a registration for `CoreContext` is missing. As fallback, Simple Injector will try to resolve `CoreContext` directly, which works because it is a concrete type. Those unregistered concrete types, however, are, by default, resolved using the Transient lifestyle.

Resolving a DbContext implementation as Transient, however, is typically not something you want. Scoped is typically better and Simple Injector is therefore correct in warning about this.

You should change your registration to the following:

```
container.Register<CoreContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

Comment: This worked, however, I also had to change to container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();